# Find a url in content a site by url it?

Tags: php, curl

I want search into content a site by url it site, if existence my url (for example: http://www.mydomain.com/) return it is TRUE else it is FALSE.

If existence url as following list, Return it is FALSE:

```
 - http://www.mydomain.com/blog?12
 - www.mydomain.com/news/maste.php
 - http://www.mydomain.com/mkds/skas/aksa.html
 - www.mydomain.com/ 
 - www.mydomain.com
```

I want just accsept(find) as(only):

`http://www.mydomain.com/` OR `http://www.mydomain.com`

I tried as:

```
    $url = 'http://www.usersite.com';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $link="/http:\/\/mydomain.com/";
    if(preg_match("/". preg_quote($link,"/"). "/m", $contents) && strstr($contents,"http://www.mydomain.com")){
        echo 'TRUE';
    } else{
        echo 'FALSE';
    }
```

But it doesn't worked, for it what that i want. How can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `preg_quote` on your link as it is already in a regex form. Try using the entire regex `/http:\/\/mydomain.com/m` instead.

```
$link="/http:\/\/mydomain.com/m";
if(preg_match($link, $contents) && false!== stripos($contents,"http://www.mydomain.com")){
    echo 'TRUE';
} else{
    echo 'FALSE';
}
```

I've also updated strstr to be stripos and to have an absolute comparison as it's not a boolean safe function.

Comment: I want just(only) search `http://www.mydomain.com/` OR `http://www.mydomain.com`, but in top code if in content existence just a url as: `www.mydomain.com/news/maste.php` return it is TRUE, but i want search(find) only url that is as: `http://www.mydomain.com/` OR `http://www.mydomain.com` in content it site.

Comment: You'll just need an extender regex in that case. Probably just specify which characters cannot follow the end. `[^A-Za-z\?]`

Comment: I don't know about it,  Please give me a demo in here: codepad.viper-7.com Or update your code in above post.

Comment: i put as: `$link="/http:\/\/mydomain.com/[^A-Za-z\?]";` but it doesn't work. What do i do?

Comment: try `$link="/http:\/\/mydomain.com\/?[^A-Za-z\?]?/";`